# How do we set the x and y axis in a chart with other fields

Tags: reporting

I have a custom object called rating with a master detail to account and rating date and rating value which is a percent.

i have also a report which shows all the ratings for an account. When i try to create a chart the only option i get to set on the y axis is record count.

I need to plot a graph with variations in rating for every month.. 
This really is the first time with charts for me.. Pls forgive my ignorance :)

I also created a custom report type to get the fields of both rating and account objects

Comment: Is your report a summary or matrix? Roughly speaking you'll need to aggregate (Max / Avg / Sum, whatever) your ratings per account in the report and then it should appear as valid chart config option. Can you maybe share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need to summarize by those account ratings and perhaps add them to a bucket since they are a percent field. You will have to play with the report a bit but it will undoubtedly need to be at least a Summary report. Maybe a Matrix report to get the values displayed how you like.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to change Y-axis data from record count to another data.
1.First in your report click on "Add Formula" in the fields
2.Then give column name.
3.In the formula section you can select your wanted field's sum or avg or largest or smallest.
4.Then click on OK.
5.Now save the report and goto dashboard refresh the page. Now yous will get the added formula column in your Y-axis. 
That's it. Hope its helpful.
Remember, only number type fields will be available on formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your y-axis generally needs to be something that is counted; have you setup any summary columns in your report, such as Average Rating?